# How to update a widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

So I am making a tkinter GUI application with python and how do you make this forget the label and not the button when the button is pressed?

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
def func():
    mainframe = tk.Frame()
    label = tk.Label(text = "Label", master = mainframe)
    label.pack()
    mainframe.pack()
def function():
    mainframe = tk.Frame()
    button = tk.Button(text = "Button", master = mainframe, command = lambda: remove(mainframe))
    button.pack()
    mainframe.pack()
    func()
def remove(mainframe):

    mainframe.forget()

function()
window.mainloop()
```

I'm pretty bad at coding, it's probably a really dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I just have to define a global variable and change it into mainframe like this. Thanks for the help though:) I really appreciate it.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    window = tk.Tk()
    def func():
        mainframe = tk.Frame()
        label = tk.Label(text = "Label", master = mainframe)
        label.pack()
        mainframe.pack()
        global x
        x = mainframe
    def function():
        mainframe = tk.Frame()
        button = tk.Button(text = "Button", master = mainframe, command = lambda: 
    remove(mainframe))
        button.pack()
        mainframe.pack()
        func()
    def remove(mainframe):

        x.forget()

    function()
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

labelframe = None


def func():
    global labelframe
    labelframe = tk.Frame()
    label = tk.Label(text="Label", master=labelframe)
    label.pack()
    labelframe.pack()


def function():
    global label
    buttonframe = tk.Frame()
    button = tk.Button(text="Button", master=buttonframe, command=lambda: remove(labelframe))
    button.pack()
    buttonframe.pack()
    func()


def remove(to_forget):
    to_forget.forget()


function()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making a new frame? In my code I have other functions and it wouldn't work with making a new frame. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `label.forget()` like I did below:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
def func():
    mainframe = tk.Frame()
    label = tk.Label(text = "Label", master = mainframe)
    label.pack()
    label.forget()
    mainframe.pack()
def function():
    mainframe = tk.Frame()
    button = tk.Button(text = "Button", master = mainframe, command = lambda: remove(mainframe))
    button.pack()
    mainframe.pack()
    func()
def remove(mainframe):

    mainframe.forget()

function()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I mean when the button is pressed